# Send authorized email in behalf of xxx@domain.com from a server that hasn't that domain

Tags: dns, spf

I'm using PHPMailer on PHP on Apache2.0 on Unix with sendmail to create a webservice that can send emails to some customers.

This server doesn't have a domain and the email will have "From: xxx@domain.com" header as they will be sent in behalf of the mother website (let's say domain.com).

Now, everything works, but Gmail and Hotmail detect my email as spam. 
It seems legit as there is currently no correlation between the sender server and the mail sender address.
What do I have to do to tell google that the email are authorized?

How do I have to set an SPF record for domain.com ?

Thank you

Comment: That's a "phishing mail". You dont have the domain "domain.com" but you say "i send this email as domain.com" so Google, Yahoo and another consider that it is false, which is true. Learn about DKIM, Identity Policies and TXT Record.

Comment: this has nothing to do  with php (yet). this is purely server/dns configuration thing, which is not a programming issue.

Comment: Yes @OlafErlandsen, I was thinking to set a TXT record of SPF type as follow for the domain.com : `v=spf1 ip4:77.77.77.77 ~all` where _77.77.77.77_ it's my sender server IP address. Do I have to add the `a mx` modifiers? Could this cause an issue for the server of the domain `domain.com` when it tries to send emails, do I have to add its address either?

Comment: I'm not sure, but i think you only need set SPF and DKIM. The MX is 'Mail eXchange record'. When i configured AWS EC2 with AWS SAS, only need set TXT and DKIM, the MX is only for receive

Comment: @OlafErlandsen Thank you, I will try and let everybody know.